# Counting occurrences of words in an array

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I've been working on something which takes a stream of characters, forms words, makes an array of the words, then creates a vector which contains each unique words and the number of times it occurs (basically a word counter).

Anyway I've not used Java in a long time, or much programming to be honest and I'm not happy with how this currently looks.  The part I have which makes the vector looks ugly to me and I wanted to know if I could make it less messy.

```
    int counter = 1;
    Vector<Pair<String, Integer>> finalList = new Vector<Pair<String, Integer>>();
    Pair<String, Integer> wordAndCount = new Pair<String, Integer>(wordList.get(1), counter); // wordList contains " " as first word, starting at wordList.get(1) skips it.

    for(int i= 1; i<wordList.size();i++){
        if(wordAndCount.getLeft().equals(wordList.get(i))){
            wordAndCount = new Pair<String, Integer>(wordList.get(i), counter++);
        }
        else if(!wordAndCount.getLeft().equals(wordList.get(i))){
            finalList.add(wordAndCount);
            wordAndCount = new Pair<String, Integer>(wordList.get(i), counter=1);
        }
    }
    finalList.add(wordAndCount); //UGLY!!
```

As a secondary question, this gives me a vector with all the words in alphabetical order (as in the array).  I want to have it sorted by occurrence, the alphabetical within that.

Would the best option be:

- Iterate down the vector, testing each occurrence int with the one above, using `Collections.swap()` if it was higher, then checking the next one above (as its now moved up 1) and so on until it's no longer larger than anything above it.  Any occurrence of 1 could be skipped.
- Iterate down the vector again, testing each element against the first element of the vector and then iterating downwards until the number of occurrences is lower and inserting it above that element.  All occurrences of 1 would once again be skipped.

The first method would doing more in terms of iterating over the elements, but the second one requires you to add and remove components of the vector (I think?) so I don't know which is more efficient, or whether its worth considering.

Comment: This post is a statement, not a question.

Comment: So the general question is "How can I make this code less messy?" right?

Comment: Also, don't use Vector in general (or Hashtable either).  They are legacy classes that force method synchronization, and create unecessary overhead when it's not needed.  If you need a synchronized collection, use Collections.sychronizedList, Collections.sychronizedMap, etc...

Answer (score 5):

Why not use a `Map` to solve your problem?

```
String[] words // your incoming array of words.
Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(String word : words) {
  if(!wordMap.containsKey(word))
    wordMap.put(word, 1);
  else
    wordMap.put(word, wordMap.get(word) + 1);
}
```

Sorting can be done using Java's sorted collections:

```
SortedMap<Integer, SortedSet<String>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, SortedSet<String>>();
for(Entry<String, Integer> entry : wordMap.entrySet()) {
  if(!sortedMap.containsKey(entry.getValue()))
    sortedMap.put(entry.getValue(), new TreeSet<String>());

  sortedMap.get(entry.getValue()).add(entry.getKey());
}
```

Nowadays you should leave the sorting to the language's libraries. They have been proven correct with the years.

Note that the code may use a lot of memory because of all the data structures involved, but that is what we pay for higher level programming (and memory is getting cheaper every second).

I didn't run the code to see that it works, but it does compile (copied it directly from eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

re: sorting, one option is to write a custom `Comparator` which first examines the number of times each word appears, then (if equal) compares the words alphabetically.

```
private final class PairComparator implements Comparator<Pair<String, Integer>> {
    public int compareTo(<Pair<String, Integer>> p1, <Pair<String, Integer>> p2) {
        /* compare by Integer */
        /* compare by String, if necessary */
        /* return a negative number, a positive number, or 0 as appropriate */
    }
}
```

You'd then sort `finalList` by calling `Collections.sort(finalList, new PairComparator());`

Answer (score 0):

How about using google guava library?

```
   Multiset<String> multiset = HashMultiset.create();
   for (String word : words) {
       multiset.add(word);
   }

   int countFoo = multiset.count("foo");
```

From their javadocs:

A collection that supports order-independent equality, like Set, but may have duplicate elements. A multiset is also sometimes called a bag.

Simple enough?

Comment: ps:  if you want inherent ordering, you could use TreeMultiset instead of HashMultiset.  Keep in mind TreeMultiset would typically have a higher insertion cost than a HashMultiset.